# Using different colors to plotting

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have values of Irf and frequencies and I need to plot a graph, which I did.
Code:

```
Irf = List[0.0897, 0.2692, 0.4487, 0.62831, 0.8078, 0.8078, 0.6283, 
   0.4487, 0.2692, 0.0897];
Freq = List[1.4814, 2.4691, 3.9506, 5.9259, 8.3950, 10.8641, 9.3827, 
   6.4197, 3.9506, 1.4814];
Both = Transpose[{Irf, Freq}]
ListPlot[Both, PlotRange -> {Full, Full}, Joined -> True, 
 Frame -> True, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Row[{Style["Irf (mA)", FontSlant -> Italic, 
      FontSize -> 15]}], 
   Row[{Style["Frequency (GHz)", FontSlant -> Italic, 
      FontSize -> 15]}]}, PlotRange -> Full(*{{0,0.045},{0,8}}*), 
 LabelStyle -> Blue
 , FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Orange, 15], ImageSize -> 900, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red}, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.5, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.01], Point[Both]}]
```

[image]
I want to divide graph on two, using two different collors.
For example first five points will be red, and the other five - green.
How can i do it?

Comment: `ListPlot[{Both[[;; 5]], Both[[6 ;;]]}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, <the rest of your options here>]`.  In general you want to look at [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)

Comment: Small tunning of your code,just  change your `Point[Both]` into `Riffle[{Red, Green}, Point /@ Partition[Both, 5]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ListPlot[{Both, Both[[;; 5]], Both[[6 ;;]]}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 Joined -> {True, False, False}, Frame -> True, 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}, 
 AspectRatio -> 0.5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question: How can we change color of the line between points?

Comment: @John, the first color in the setting of `PlotStyle` is the color of the lines between points, that is `PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}`  makes the lines blue.